# HDP 2.5: Zeppelin won't run Notebook in Kerberos-enabled cluster

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-zeppelin, ambari

I set up a Hadoop cluster with Hortonworks Data Platform 2.5 and Ambari 2.4. I also added the Zeppelin service to the cluster installation via Ambari UI.

Since I enabled Kerberos, I can't run the Zeppelin Notebooks anymore. When I click "Run paragraph" or "Run all paragraphs" nothing seems to happen. I also don't get any new entries in my logs in `/var/log/zeppelin/`. Before enabling Kerberos I was able to run the paragraphs.

I tried some example notebooks, and also some of mine, same problem: nothing happens... Tried with admin and non-admin users.

Here are my "Spark" and "sh" interpreter settings (other paragraphs e.g. %sql also don't work):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial below captures the configuration of Ambari and Hadoop Kerberos:

[Configuring Ambari and Hadoop for Kerberos](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.4.2.0/bk_ambari-security/content/ch_configuring_amb_hdp_for_kerberos.html)